# IntelliJ: Launch Run-configuration from the embeded terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, intellij-plugin

Lets say I have **run-config1** and **run-config2** setup for my project in IntelliJ. 
I know there are ways of adding custom shell code to be perfomed before/after a build run, but that's not what I want to do.

Is there a way of calling them from the embedded terminal?

Comment: I was only able to store the run configuration in an `.xml` file in the `.idea\runConfigurations` - by selecting the `Share` check box. Now you need an external launcher...

Comment: thanks. unfortunately that's too much effort for my liking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of IntelliJ IDEA 14 there is no such way. You can write a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA that will handle a command like "idea.sh run configuration-name" and start the run configuration in the existing instance, but this is fairly non-trivial.