# How to get the command for an Run Configuration in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I right on JUnit test class file, a run configuration is formed. I just need to click the run button.  How I get the right command or executing process for the run configutration in order to run it in shell?

Comment: Simple: just look at the docs to see which parameters you have to pass.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way to this. Idea assembles the classpath from your modul configuration and the [AppMain](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/10.0/com/intellij/rt/execution/application/AppMain.java) class opens a `Sockets` to communicate with `IDEA` and provide infomation about the unit test process.

Running the same command `IDEA` uses in a shell will not print the results to `stdout`. It does not help you, even if get that command running from your shell.

You tagged your question as `android-gradle` so I guess you want to execute android unit tests.

If you want to know how to run unit or android test using gradle in your shell, you can read [Unit testing support](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing).

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid you can't do that in a simple way. Accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584459/intellij-launch-run-configuration-from-the-embeded-terminal) says that you might have to write your own IntelliJ/Android Studio plugin.